# Trouble with nested resources

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm new to Ember, and I think I bit off more than I can chew with this practice app, but I intend to learn. I might be completely conceptually off, if so, feel free to offer a better structure for my use case.

My (abbreviated) routing looks more or less like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('shops', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.resource('shop', { path: ':shop_id' }, function() {
      this.resource('items', { path: 'admin'}, function() {
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The intention is that the user will select a shop, then get a list of all possible items with checkboxes where he can decide which are available in that shop and which aren't. So far, I'm just trying to display the list of all items, but it's not working. However, the list of shops - no problem whatsoever.

- URL: `/`

  Works. `model` is all shops.
- URL: `/1`

  Works. `model` is the shop with ID 1.
- URL: `/1/admin`

  **Error while processing route: items.index Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object**

Both `shops` and `items` controllers are identical:

```
// app/controllers/shops.js
// app/controllers/items.js
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

The routes are nearly identical:

```
// app/routes/shops/index.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('shop');
  }
});

// app/routes/items/index.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('item');
  }
});
```

The `shop` controller does not exist, and the `shop.index` route is trivial:

```
// app/routes/shop/index.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({});
```

What gives?

**EDIT:** [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/halavomece/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Is there any reason to keep items as resource instead of route

Comment: @Vaibhav: Maybe not. As I said - newbie. But since I have items as a model, it made sense to make it a resource. If I made it into a route (shop.admin), how would I get the item list? Do I need to `needs: "items"` in the `shop` controller?

Comment: I think needs wont be required in this case, according to me, for a array conroller the values should be array. I guess your values would be coming  as non array.

Comment: @Vaibhav: I don't understand what you mean. The values *are* arrays. If I took out the `items` resource out from under `shop`, it worked; the issue comes only when nesting. Maybe `:shop_id` was used to automagically look up one of the `items`? I don't know. But I just tried to write a route that would access `items`, and failed; the property is never invoked.

Comment: I mean to say that, if we create an controller using ArrayController, then the model should return values as array. So can you check that model hook inside route is returning array values(i.e inside  [ ]). Let me see more closely if I can figure out something.

Comment: Both `items` and `shops` routes' model returns a RSVP that resolves to an array.

Comment: Can you provide a JSBin? Don't have enough information to debug. Ember starting point: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys: Sorry, took some time (sleep + figuring out how to simplify and translate from Ember-CLI). [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/halavomece/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your JSBin turns out to be rather simple. In the simplified router in your original post you have `this.resource('items', { path: 'admin'}, function() {});`.
Since you pass a function to `this.resource` that means it has an implicit nested `this.route('index')`.

However, in your JSBin, you have `this.resource('items, { path: 'admin' });`.
Since you are not passing a function in this case, there is no implicit `index` route.

The solution is either to add the function bit, or rename `App.ItemsIndexRoute` to `App.ItemsRoute` and `data-template-name="items/index"` to `data-template-name="items"`.

JSBin with the latter: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dahuge/2/edit?html,js

**P.S.** I've also prepared a JSBin using just `this.route` which is currently more future-friendly: http://jsbin.com/mifamu/9/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Answered on IRC by one very helpful "locks". Some problems remain, but the big question has been answered with [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mifamu/7/edit?html,js,output). My biggest confusion came from misunderstanding how URLs are handled, and what the role of `link-to` helper was. What I needed most was the change in the `ItemsController`:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['shop'],
  shop: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.shop.model')
});
```

which would make `shop` accessible, and a mistake in a template saying `items` instead of `model`.